# For a certain method, How to find all possible combinations of call hierarchy recursively that invoke this method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, call-hierarchy

By using IntelliJ IDEA `Find Usages` feature, we will find only the first level of method usages, but I need to find all possible combinations of **call hierarchy recursively** that invoke this method

For example, given the below **call hierarchy**:

- `MyClass.myMethod()` used inside both `Class1.method1()`and `Class2.method2()`
- `Class1.method1()` used inside both `Class3.method3()` and `Class4.method4()`
- `Class2.method2()` used inside both `Class5.method5()` and `Class6.method6()`

[image]

By using the `Find Usages` Feature, the result will show the first-level usage only:

- `MyClass.myMethod()` used inside `Class1.method1()`
- `MyClass.myMethod()` used inside `Class2.method2()`

But I need to find all possible combinations of **call hierarchy recursively** that invoke my method, so the expected answer should be like this:

- `MyClass.myMethod()` used inside `Class1.method1()`, `Class1.method1()` used inside `Class3.method3()`
- `MyClass.myMethod()` used inside `Class1.method1()`, `Class1.method1()` used inside `Class4.method4()`
- `MyClass.myMethod()` used inside `Class2.method2()`, `Class1.method2()` used inside `Class5.method3()`
- `MyClass.myMethod()` used inside `Class2.method2()`, `Class1.method2()` used inside `Class6.method4()`

Comment: Have you tried `Navigate | Call Hierarchy`?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841421/how-do-i-find-all-execution-paths-that-use-a-certain-method-in-a-java-class

Answer (score 0):

Simply by:

- Focus on the method
- Then select the `Navigate` menu then > `Call Hierarchy` option
  [or use the related keyboard shortcut for `Call Hierarchy` according to your OS]